# Не получается добавить запись в БД через форму, в которой есть EntityType::class

Tags: php, form, orm, symfony, forms

У меня 2 таблицы `Author` и `Book`, связаны 1:м, при добавлении книги мне нужно вытащить в выпадающий список всех авторов, если я использую просто `TextType::class`  - он добавляет, но когда использую `EntityType` - пишет ошибку:

> "An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO book (id, Name, Author, Articul, Date_en) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [66, "dfs", {}, "243", null]:
>   Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class AppBundle\Entity\Author could not be converted to string"

src\AppBundle\Controller\SecondController:

```
$form = $this->createForm(BookType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this ->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $books = $form->getData();
        $em->persist($books);
        $em->flush();
       $this->addFlash('success','We saved a book with id='.$books->getId());    
        return $this->redirectToRoute('third');
    }

    return $this->render('lucky/edit.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
```

src\AppBundle\Form\Type\BookType

```
class BookType extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('Name', TextType::class)
       ->add('Author', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Author',
        'choice_label' => 'fio',
        'choice_value' => 'id',
    ])
             ->add('Articul', TextType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Book',
    ));
}

}
```

Book.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Book
 */
class Book
{
/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $name;
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Book", inversedBy="id")
 */
/**
 * @var int
 */
private $author;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $articul;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 */
private $dateEn;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 *
 * @return Book
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set author
 *
 * @param integer $author
 *
 * @return Book
 */
public function setAuthor($author)
{
    $this->author = $author;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get author
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getAuthor()
{
    return $this->author;
}

/**
 * Set articul
 *
 * @param string $articul
 *
 * @return Book
 */
public function setArticul($articul)
{
    $this->articul = $articul;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get articul
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getArticul()
{
    return $this->articul;
}

/**
 * Set dateEn
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dateEn
 *
 * @return Book
 */
public function setDateEn($dateEn)
{
    $this->dateEn = $dateEn;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateEn
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDateEn()
{
    return $this->dateEn;
}
}
```

Author.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

/**
 * Author
 */
class Author
{
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Book", mappedBy="author",cascade={"persist", 
"remove"})

 */
/**
 * @var int
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $fIO;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set fIO
 *
 * @param string $fIO
 *
 * @return Author
 */
public function setFIO($fIO)
{
    $this->fIO = $fIO;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get fIO
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFIO()
{
    return $this->fIO;
}
}
```

Comment: А как у вас объявлено поле Author в сущности Book?

Comment: /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Book", inversedBy="id")
     */
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $author;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не показали класс `AppBundle\Entity\Author`, но в показанном вами исключении говорится, что не удается объект привести к строке.

> Object of class AppBundle\Entity\Author could not be converted to
>   string

Поэтому предположу, что в классе сущности не реализован метод `__toString()`. Если это так, попробуйте его добавить.

src/AppBundle/Entity/Author.php

```
public function __toString()
{
    return (string) $this->fIO;
}
```

Comment: Я решил вывести $books, в результате вот что: AppBundle\Entity\Book Object
(
    [id:AppBundle\Entity\Book:private] => 
    [name:AppBundle\Entity\Book:private] => dfcfc
    [author:AppBundle\Entity\Book:private] => AppBundle\Entity\Author Object
        (
            [id:AppBundle\Entity\Author:private] => 2
            [fIO:AppBundle\Entity\Author:private] => Достоевский
        )

    [articul:AppBundle\Entity\Book:private] => fcfc
    [dateEn:AppBundle\Entity\Book:private] => 
)

Comment: `'choice_label' => 'fio'` `[fIO:AppBundle\Entity\Author:private]` Я не знаю, важен ли регистр, но все же, попробуйте исправить. Еще вы показываете сущность Book, которая связана по полю `author` сама с собой: `ManyToOne(targetEntity="Book"` это просто опечатка?

Comment: И покажите все таки вашего `AppBundle\Entity\Author`, пожалуйста

Comment: Author вывел, да, вы правы, опечатка

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы он мне выковырял id выбранного мной автора, но этого не происходит

Comment: Попробуйте все таки добавить `__toString()` в `AppBundle\Entity\Author`, как я предлагал в ответе. Id автоматотм доктрина подставляет, когда запрос готовит.

Comment: Вообще стрнно связи настроены, если у вас все именно так, как вы показываете, то надо бы пересмотреть их. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: Мне ->add('Author', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Author',
        'choice_label' => 'fio',
        'choice_value' => 'id',
    ]) ничего не надо менять?

Comment: забавно, теперь такая штука Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "Петров"

Comment: Сработало, спасибо большое

Comment: Рад, что все у вас получилось)